# Windows 2003 Server, can't connect to an SSL Site from IE

Tags: browser, troubleshooting, internet-explorer, windows-server-2003, ssl

I am trying to connect to connect to [www.czebox.cz](http://www.czebox.cz) using internet explorer on Windows 2003 server.

If you have a server to test from please do, and you'll notice that it does not connect instead returns - Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

From Firefox it works fine on the server.

From Windows 7 it works fine in Internet Explorer.

How can I get it to work in Windows 2003 Server using IE?

Comment: This sounds fishy. I'd be wary of that link.

Comment: @rodey - Mmm, hardly fishy since its a government provided service

Comment: @JL: doesn't that make it *more* fishy, not less?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install KB 938397 on windows 2003 to support new SHA-2 certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on win 2003 and IE7. It had been working before they chaged certificates throught weekend. But new certificates didn't resolve it for me.

See: http://www.datoveschranky.info/clanek/341

Thanks

Martin

Comment: New certificates didn't solve it for me too. We have a situation where we are unable to make a connection to test environment from any Windows 2003 Server. I tried deleting all certificates and then testing from Internet Explorer, but this too didn't help.

Comment: hotfix KB 938397 - fixed the issue

Comment: Martin are you developing a windows based solution?